# Use automator to batch rename images

Tags: screenshot, automator

I have a whole folder of screenshots with file names like this:

```
http_www.mozilla.org.png
http_www.google.com.png
```

I want to remove every element before the www. and every element after the .org or .com

What should I do in automator on mac to achieve something like this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to rename the files or just return a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to rename them, try this AppleScript:

```
   tell application "Finder" to set myFiles to files of (choose folder)
repeat with aFile in myFiles
    tell application "System Events" to set fileName to aFile's name
    set newName to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of fileName & " | sed 's/.*www\\.\\([A-Za-z0-9]*\\).*\\(\\.png$\\)/\\1\\2/'"
    tell application "System Events" to set aFile's name to newName
end repeat
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, that's what I'm trying to do. I'll try it now and see if it works. I'll get back to you

Comment: actually, stupid question but since I've never used automator before. Where do I tell application finder to set the files? I only see preference options settings for finder. Also where do I input the shell scripts?

Comment: The script above can be run directly from AppleScript Editor. The choose folder command asks you to select a folder which contains the files to process.

Comment: Okay I get it now and I tried it, works perfectly. Btw, what if I have an image like this: www.mozilla.org/en-US/mission/statement.png I only want this part "mozilla" and "png". Everything else I don't need. So the end result should just be mozilla.png  Is this possible?

Comment: Or alternatively, where can I read up on how to use this part "set newName to do shell script "sed 's/http_www\\.\\(.*\\)\\.png/\\1/' <<< " & quoted form of fileName" thanks

Comment: umm okay I thought it would kinda be like a simple regex tutorial but it looks really complicated and out of my league. Could please modify the script a tiny bit to include what I need? I just need to process these images and upload to my site.  Thanks

Comment: now the result is mozilla.org/en-US/mission/statement, no longer having .png at the end

Comment: so basically what I need is: remove everything matching "http_www." and remove everything from "org" onwards but keep the final ".png" and the contents between "http_www" and "org"

Comment: Amazing, you're a God with sed here. One last thing, what is the element I need to add here "([A-Za-z0-9]*\\)" so that if the URL has a symbol in it e.g. a dash or something. Thanks

Comment: I would up vote this answer if I could but I don't have enough points for now

Comment: You can accept the answer by clicking the check mark. To add a symbol simply add it to [A-Za-z0-9]. If you wanted to include a dash it would read:  [A-Za-z0-9-]Also, lets delete a bunch of these comments to make the post readable for other users.

Comment: Thank you so much adayzdone, you just saved me a few days of googling  :D